# How to include spaces in forfiles

Tags: batch-file

I want to move the log files from multiple locations to another folder with the current date in the same location , and source path is taken from a text file. And the source path contains spaces due to which errors are occurred.

Below is the script :

```
ECHO ON
set curr_date=%DATE:~10,4%%DATE:~4,2%%DATE:~7,2%
for /f "tokens=*" %%i in (C:\Users\kyckeams\Desktop\Batch\source.txt) do (
set "location=%%i"
call :Move
)
goto:EOF
:Move
cd %location%
cd /D %location%
mkdir %curr_date%
forfiles /p %location% /m *.log /d -2 /c "cmd /c move %location%*.* %location%%curr_date%"
PAUSE
```

And the error im getting is :

---

```
C:\Users\kyckeams\Desktop\Batch>ECHO ON

C:\Users\kyckeams\Desktop\Batch>set curr_date=20131102

C:\Users\kyckeams\Desktop\Batch>for /F "tokens=*" %i in (C:\Users\kyckeams\Desktop\Batch\source.txt) do (set "location=%i" call :Move)

C:\Users\kyckeams\Desktop\Batch>(set "location=D:\kycintg\KenyaSpecificServices\Unidoc_DML_Executor_Kenya\Log Files\" call :Move )

C:\Users\kyckeams\Desktop\Batch>cd D:\kycintg\KenyaSpecificServices\Unidoc_DML_Executor_Kenya\Log Files\

C:\Users\kyckeams\Desktop\Batch>cd /D D:\kycintg\KenyaSpecificServices\Unidoc_DML_Executor_Kenya\Log Files\

D:\kycintg\KenyaSpecificServices\Unidoc_DML_Executor_Kenya\Log Files>mkdir 20131102

D:\kycintg\KenyaSpecificServices\Unidoc_DML_Executor_Kenya\Log Files>forfiles /p D:\kycintg\KenyaSpecificServices\Unidoc_DML_Executor_Kenya\Log Files\ /m *.log /d -2 /c "cmd /c move D:\kycintg\KenyaSpecificServices\Unidoc_DML_Executor_Kenya \Log Files\*.* D:\kycintg\KenyaSpecificServices\Unidoc_DML_Executor_Kenya\Log Files\20131102"
ERROR: Invalid argument/option - 'Files\'. Type "FORFILES /?" for usage.
```

Press any key to continue . . .

---

Help needed.. please...

Comment: Now , Im able to move the files to the destination but im getting this error as mentioned below:
D:\kycintg\KenyaSpecificServices\UNIDOC~1\LOGFIL~1>forfiles /p D:\kycintg\KenyaSpecificServices\UNIDOC~1\LOGFIL~1\ /m *.log /d -2 /c "cmd /c move D:\kycintg\KenyaSpecificServices\UNIDOC~1\LOGFIL~1\*.* D:\kycintg\KenyaSpecificServices\UNIDOC~1\LOGFIL~1\20131102"

D:\kycintg\KenyaSpecificServices\UNIDOC~1\LOGFIL~1\KYCEMAUnbarring_3.log
D:\kycintg\KenyaSpecificServices\UNIDOC~1\LOGFIL~1\UNIDOC_OFFLINEDBLOG.log
        2 file(s) moved.
The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect.

Comment: if there are multiple files in the source location then im getting this error.. The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try with short paths (short path of a file does not contain spaces):

```
for /f "tokens=*" %%i in (C:\Users\kyckeams\Desktop\Batch\source.txt) do (
set "location=%%~dpsfni"
call :Move
)
echo %location%
```

Comment: can i also know what does this ~dpsfn do?

Comment: It returns the short path\filename.  Unfortunately it has a bug that appears every so often and is not 100% reliable.

Answer (score 1):

Forfiles uses `0x22` where a double quote would go
(hex 22 is an Ascii 34 and is the double quote character)

so this would quote the terms:

edit: **echo** is added below - see what this segment echos in the forfiles command.

```
"cmd /c echo move 0x22%location%*.*0x22 0x22%location%%curr_date%0x22"
```

Also note that your log file shows an added space after "kenya" in the move command, but it is not in both terms, and is not in the code as pasted.

Comment: Check your posted log file `\Unidoc_DML_Executor_Kenya \Log Files\*.*`  See the space?  Check my edit above